# How to change the border around a LoopingSelector

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've been messing around trying to change this red border around the LoopingSelector in code, and in Blend. I just can't figure out how to do it. Here's a picture so you have an idea of what I'm talking about.

[image]

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="1">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="KiloTemplate">
                <Grid Background="DarkBlue">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="54" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="kg" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector x:Name="loopingSelectorStarost" Margin="12" Width="128" ItemSize="128,128" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StarostTemplate}" ManipulationStarted="loopingSelector_ManipulationStarted">
            <toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector.DataSource>
                <local:NumberDataSource Privzeti="18" Minimum="13" Maximum="99" />
            </toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector.DataSource>
        </toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector>
    </Grid>
```

**EDIT:** Here's the soulution, thanks to Chris. W. I copied the style from the Generic.xaml file in the Phone Toolkit samples. I changed the `<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />` in the `Selected` Visual State. Here's the code:

```
<Style TargetType="toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelectorItem">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="root" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Background="Transparent" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Normal" To="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                    <VisualTransition From="Expanded" To="Normal" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.8" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Duration="0">
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="DarkGray" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Duration="0">
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="Transform"/>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>

                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="background" Margin="0" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>

                            <Border x:Name="border" Opacity="0" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>

                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by finding the template for it, a quick solution search for `TargetType="primitives:LoopingSelectorItem"` should expose it pretty quick or you could likely get to it in Blend.

Once you have the template you'll just locate the `Border` or `Rectangle` object in the template that's causing that border.

However that may not even be necessary if the property is bound to the template already. Can you set something like `BorderBrush` directly to it? I'd have to load something up to look so I'm just guessing at this point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can set the BorderBrush directly, but it doesn't change anything. A search for TargetType="..." doesn't return anythhing. Editing the template in blend and I can only get the Border and ItemsPanel, but not one property changes what I want to change.